# flutter download automatic image and save it in assets

Tags: flutter, dart, svg, download, assets

in my app,I want to use SVG images from the asset file.
but I want to check them in-the app, if the image asset is different from my image network from the server, I download the image network and replace it in my image asset and again read it from the asset to show them.
how can I do that?

`bool showSvg = false;`

```
 void compareSvg(){
     if(value['svgimage']['name'] != Image.profileSvg){

     // how download svg network and replace it to assetfile

       }else{
      showSvg = true; });}
```

and its my code example :

```
 showSvg 
  ?SvgPicture.asset(Image.profileSvg) 
  :SvgPicture.asset(Image.newProfileSvg),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not compare images (technically you can, but it very complicated task) and replace assets file. You need to cache you image after first downloading, and set your asset as placeholder before your image are downloaded. Look in to dock [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/images/cached-images).

**Edited:**

Okay. I don't get your answer about svg, but if true here solution
Add this [pub](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_cache_manager) for file caching to your project. And this code may help:

```
  File? _downloaded;

  void _fetchImage() async {
    const key = "profile";
    const url =
        "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/02/SVG_logo.svg";
    final file = await DefaultCacheManager().getSingleFile(url, key: key);

    setState(() {
      _downloaded = file;
    });
  }

  Widget _svgImageFetcher() {
    _fetchImage();

    Widget networkSvg;

    if (_downloaded == null) {
      networkSvg = SvgPicture.asset("assets/images/profile.svg");
    } else {
      networkSvg = SvgPicture.file(_downloaded!);
    }

    return Column(children: [Expanded(child: networkSvg)]);
  }
```

Just put _svgImageFetcher() Widget where you want to display image. And change default svg image and url.

Comment: ok, the cache SVG image is different.
but I don't understand how can I do it. more explain, please.

Comment: On second run, your cached image would be opened from file storage, really fast. So for user it would looks like downloaded image opened immediately.

Comment: @user17838882, let me clarify. You store svg images on server?

Comment: i want to use it from asset (offline) . but maybe want to change them later, so want to change them from server. 
i want to compare the name of SVG from asset and server
if there are different, I change it and replace new svg in app

Comment: @user17838882, so on server side you store svg files?

Comment: i just want to download svg and replace it in Previous file.